# Reload attribute table does not work for attribute changed by dataProvider

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table

In QGIS2.18, I'm changing feature attributes using the following two methods:

**dataProvider:**

```
attrs = { 0 : "hello", 1 : 123 }
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
```

**layer object:**

```
layer.startEditing()
layer.changeAttributeValue(fid, fieldIndex, value)
layer.commitChanges()
```

I keep the attribute table open, and monitor the changes. The first method dataProvider is not able to update the attribute table on the fly, even the "reload table" button on the top menu of the table does not work. I have to re-open the table to see the changes. The second method is working, the attribute table gets instantly updated.

I would like to stay with the dataProvider method but not sure how to get instantly updated attribute table?

Comment: have you tried layer.triggerRepaint(), layer. reload() or layer.dataProvider().reloadData()?